# Prove multiplication in fields is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is Problem $16$ from Halmos' Linear Algebra Problem Book.

The problem asks whether or not multiplication must be commutative in a field.

The solution uses the distributive properties $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ and $(a+b)c=ac+bc$ with $(0+1)x$ and $x(0+1)$ to show that both $0x=x0=0$.

From here it states that this implies that multiplication is both commutative and associative. I can't seem to grasp the underlying logic of this. How does this imply that $xy=yx$ for every $x$ and $y$ in the field?

Thanks for any help!

-Tusike

Comment: How does Halmos define a field?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For many authors, commutativity of multiplication is part of the definition of a "field". It might therefore help if you posted Halmos' definition. Second, the properties you mention from "the solution" hold in various non-cummutative settings, so something about this "solution" seems suspect. Is this "solution" reliable?

Comment: The definition given in the book:
"A **field** is a set F with two operations + and × such that with + the entire set F is an abelian group, with × the diminished set F* [obtained by omitting the additive 0 identity element from F] is an abelian group, and such that the distributive laws [the ones I wrote] are true."

The solution is given in the same book, I suppose it is reliable...

Comment: Ah, $F^*$ is assumed to be abelian, so the only question that remains is whether or not $0$ commutes with every other element of $F$.

Comment: It's all clear now, thank you very much. I see now this was a rather silly question, but the way the question was phrased made me forget about the field being commutative in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the pages preceeding the problem:
[image]

The author is intending to ask if *all* pairs multiplicatively commute, since we've been given that all nonzero products commute.

Thus the only thing left to prove is that $0$ commutes with everything.

---

As an aside, keep in mind that some older books, especially ones translated from French abstract algebra, use the word *field* to mean *division ring* (a "noncommutative field"). Nowadays fields are mostly assumed to be commutative rings, though.

Answer (score -1):

Start here:

a*0 + a
= a*0 + a*1   (Because it's a group, it has a multiplicative identity element 1)

= a*(0 + 1)   (Using the distributive law)

= a*1         (0 + 1 = 1)

= a + 0     (0 is the additive identity element, which exists because it's a group)

So a*0 + a = a + 0   (Now add the inverses of a to both sides)

=> a*0 + a - a = a - a + 0

=> a*0 = 0 (Because he element + inverse equals the additive inverse, which is 0; and then an element + the additive inverse, is the element)

Do the same thing, except use 0 * a first. You've proved multiplication with 0 is commutative, which is all that matters, because we know that multiplication with between every other element is commutative

Comment: The question wasn't asking to prove $a0 = 0 = 0a$, but why this implies that multiplication is commutative.